# How to execute query over Amazon Athena with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

how to connect Amazon Athena with Ruby and execute query over Amazon Athena and get result.

we not able to find any gem or example with help us to connect Amazon Athena in ruby.

Please provide any reference using which we can use to build connection with Amazon Athena and build a custom query executor in Ruby.

just to clarify my application on production so changing SDK from Ruby to JRuby is not a suitable option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [May 19th 2017](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2017-05-19.html), Amazon Athena supports query execution via SDK and CLI.

[Ruby API client for Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Athena/Client.html) @ docs.aws.amazon.com

[Source code of aws-sdk-athena](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-athena) @ github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

Answer (score 1):

I found that the official Amazon SDK for athena was a bit complicated, so I made a new gem called [Athens](https://github.com/getletterpress/athens) that wraps the SDK in a nicer interface:

```rb
conn = Athens::Connection.new(database: 'sample')
query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

Answer (score 0):

If using JRuby is not acceptable, there is another option that could work - but be warned that it's not 100% Ruby!

You could set up a Java [Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) that encapsulates the query logic, taking in search parameters and then connecting directly to Athena using the JDBC driver.

Then call the Lambda function from Ruby - either via HTTP or through the [Ruby client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html#invoke-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I like to have pure Ruby implmentation but it not possible right now.

Comment: I have implmented jetty server with rest services in java which take query string as paramater and return response.. this will resolve my problem for now.. but this is adding one more over head to maintain one additionl service.

Comment: your suggestion with Lambda function is good but i not like to pay more with using more service right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using  Lambda function is good alternative but if some one not like to pay additional service amount then batter to implment small application with jetty using rest service in JAVA with sql query as parameter and response text as output(your prefer format) will give you workaround to move on.

Answer (score -1):

JRuby is required. Athena offers only JDBC driver. It works only in JRE.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i not prefer to go with change SDK.

Comment: This is no longer true, if it ever was. There is an ODBC driver as well.